# Render to a unsigned integer texture2D

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to render to an (RGBA32UI) unsigned-integer texture2D and then read pixel data using glReadPixels. But it does not work

```
GLuint FramebufferName = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

// The texture we're going to render to
GLuint renderedTexture;
glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32UI, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, GL_RGB_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);

// The depth buffer
GLuint depthrenderbuffer;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthrenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, windowWidth, windowHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthrenderbuffer);

GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers); // "1" is the size of DrawBuffers

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

render_scene();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_READ_BUFFER, FramebufferName);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

    GLuint data[3];
    for (int i=0; i < windowWidth; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < windowHeight; j++)
        {
            glReadPixels(i, j, 1, 1, GL_RGB32UI, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data);

            if (data[0] == 1 && data[1] == 2 && data[2] == 3)
                int a = 1;
        }
```

Shader (GLSL)

```
#version 450 core


 out uvec3 output_color;

void main()
{   
   output_color = uvec3(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Is there anyone experienced this problem? Please, help me.

Comment: In what way it doesn't work?

Comment: Is it C or C++? Please add a tag

Comment: What does [glCheckFramebufferStatus](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xhtml) return?

Comment: The problem could also be that you simply don't render anything to pixel [1,1]. But without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
glBindBuffer(GL_READ_BUFFER, FramebufferName);
```

is wrong. `glBindBuffer` does not have the target `GL_READ_BUFFER`, so this should result in an `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error. (You should really add some error checking, preferably via [debug output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) if available.) You can never bind an FBO with `glBindBuffer`. FBOs can only be bound with `glBindFramebuffer`. What You actually wanted to do is:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
```

Also note that `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ...);` is just a shortcut to bind `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` and `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` at once.